# Pass Generic Model to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have this in my Page setup;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ILocationsFormViewModel>" %>
```

And the interface looks like this;

```
public interface ILocationsFormViewModel<T>
{
    List<TopLocation<T>> Locations { get; set; }
    List<TrendingItem<ITrendItem>> TrendingLocations { get; set; }
}
```

`T` is either `ITopHotel` or `ITopShop` etc etc with no properties

The problem is I get this error when I goto the View;

> CS0305: Using the generic type 'ILocationsFormViewModel' requires
>   '1' type arguments

Does anyone know how I can pass a class that has a Generic type to a view?

Comment: How do you plan to use the generic model (simplistic question I know)?My point is more that you're unable to apply generic constraints to the Model so what value is there in being able to supply a generic type as the model? How would your view know what properties would be available if you can't tell it with constraints? I think you'd be better off using an anonymous model.

Comment: There are lists on the ILocationsFormViewModel. Those lists are of a generic type and I can then check the type and render a particular control based on that type.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to achieve what I was in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980944/reducing-code-duplication-using-html-helpers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the generic type parameter in there:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ILocationsFormViewModel<T>>" %>
```

Comment: No that only causes this: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

Comment: You're right.. thinking about it I'm with M Babcock here.. without being able to place constraints on a generic parameter you are no better off than just using object.. and no generics required

Comment: +1 OK, so I simply inherit from <object> and then I can test the type within the aspx code.  Job done.  Thanks!